# Handlebars.js if/else helper function

Tags: javascript, html, function, handlebars.js, helper

I am trying to get my function to return true or false but I cant seem to get it to work. This is what I have

Javascript:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("longDesc", function() {
var longDesc = localDataStore.get("fb_userinfo").mentions_longdesc;
if ((longDesc) === true)
    return true;
else
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
{{#if longDesc}}
 <a class="desc">{{postDescLong}}</a>
 {{else}}
 <a class="desc">{{postDesc}}</a>
 {{/if longDesc}}
```

How can I get it to post the long description if its true and short description if its false? the data is being stored in localstorage.

**EDIT**

I figured it out, I can just do:

JS:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("Desc", function(longDesc, shortDesc) {
    if ((localDataStore.get("fb_userinfo").mentions_longdesc) === true)
    return longDesc;
else
    return shortDesc;
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="desc">{{Desc postDescLong postDesc}}</a>
```

The question has been solved, I do not have enough reputation to solve it myself.

Comment: Is it a typo that you are registering the helper as "longDesc" and using the helper "iflongDesc"?

Comment: it's suppose to be an if statement, I want it to post the long description if it returns true and post the short description if the function returns false

Comment: solved my own question thanks!

Comment: you can use handlebars subexpressions to use multiple helpers together.